# How to convert excel to pdf and save to specific file location

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to convert an excel sheet to pdf than save it to a folder on my desktop, however, I keep getting a run time error of 1004 - application-defined or object defined error. I have placed the code below. Can anyone please assist?

```
    Private Sub pdfAlternate()

    Dim strPathLocation As String
    Dim strFilename As String
    Dim strPathFile As String
    Dim fileSaveName As String
    Dim fileSavePath As String

    Dim pdfOpenAfterPublish As Boolean

    strPathLocation = Worksheets("Form").Range("C11").Value
    strFilename = Worksheets("Form").Range("L11").Value
    fileSaveName = strPathLocation & "_" & strFilename

    fileSavePath = "C:\Users\fou55227\Desktop\BMW" & "\" & fileSaveName & "_" & Format(Date, "MM.DD.YYYY") & ".pdf"

             ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Form").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
                fileSavePath _
                , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
                :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

Debug.Print fileSaveName
Debug.Print fileSavePath

    End Sub
```

Comment: In which line do you get the error?

Comment: Side note: the `ChDir ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"` is not necessary. I would `Debug.Print fileSaveName` to check that it actually is what you think it is. `strPathLocation & strFilename` - should there be a backslash between the two? Why do you concatenate a path - `"C:\Users\jerry\Desktop\BMW" & "\"` - with `strPathFile`, which presumably already includes the path?

Comment: `fileSaveName = strPathLocation & "_" & strFilename` - now this looks even more suspect. Is `strPathLocation` really a path?

Comment: I modified the code and it worked. I just hope I'm not shooting myself in the foot without the dims

Comment: Always declare all variables.

Comment: I recommend always to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)* and declare all variables (otherwise make sure you have a bullet proof foot).